# Prevent Visual Studio from adding child controls

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, custom-controls, markup

I have a bit of a strange issue here.  I created a custom control as such:

```
public class Textbox : System.Web.WebControls.Placeholder
{

    if( [certain criteria are met])
        this.Controls.Add(new System.Web.WebControls.Textbox());

}
```

When working in Visual Studio's designer mode, anytime I add one of my textboxes to the page:

```
<myControls:Textbox id="txtTest" runat="server" />
```

Visual studio has a habit of changing my markup to the following:

```
<myControls:Textbox id="txtTest" runat="server" >
    <asp:Textbox runat="server" />
</myControls:Textbox>
```

This changes the final output markup so that two textboxes appear.  Is there a way to prevent visual studio from doing this?

EDIT:
As per request, here is the page markup

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestApp.Test" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="MyControls.WebControls" Namespace="MyControls.WebControls" TagPrefix="myControls" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server">Test Label:</asp:Label> 
        <myControls:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" Width="80px"></myControls:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: There's probably something wrong with your user control.

Comment: I don't think so, VS is compiling the page and determining that the textbox would be added, so it adds it, but the conditions might happen so that the texbox is not added.

Comment: Post the markup for your user control

Comment: Sorry, not a user control.  Just a page.  I'll post the markup for that though.

Comment: it looks like you are extending a PlaceHolder but your control is called TextBox. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's happening because your class inherits from the `PlaceHolder` control, which implements the `TemplateControl` class. I don't know if there was a reason for this, but it seems like it would be more approriate if you inherited from the `TextBox` control instead.

**EDIT**

Since you're using logic to render one of several controls, I would inherit from the `WebControl` class instead. This will allow you render basically anything you want. Although I must admit, what you're trying to do is probably going to require a substantial amount of work.

Comment: hehe I just posted that as comment after I looked closely at his code ;)

Comment: @Icarus The reason it inherits from placeholder is because other types of controls can be placed inside it.  Our idea of a textbox is that it matches up with a record in a DB.  These textboxes can essentially be a textbox, combobox, or suggestion box.  There is a well thought through reason for this but I don't want to create too long a post.  I can explain if it's pertinent.

Comment: Even if you inherit from the TextBox control, you can still add other controls in the render method. Inheriting from the `TextBox` control just serves as a baseline. For example, I've done this to include validators in my custom textbox.

Comment: Yes but can you add controls that replace the original control?  If I inherit from textbox, I would basically need the ability to say this = new RadComboBox(); // [Telerik Control]

Comment: In that case, you should just inherit from the `WebControl` class. A `PlaceHolder` is definitely not the control to inherit from.

Comment: I believe that may be the answer.  I feel kind of silly for not thinking of it.  In case it doesn't work, is there any way to seal the placeholders Controls property?  I know it's not good practice, but changing this might break 100 other things.

Comment: Seal it how? Make it so that it's not accessible through the editor? You could probably do that using the `EditorBrowsable` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the issue correctly, you are having problems at design time and not runtime.

If this is the case, you should wrap your control add code with a test that ensures it is only executed when you are not in design mode. For example:

```
    if ((!this.InDesignMode) && ( [certain criteria are met]))
    this.Controls.Add(new System.Web.WebControls.Textbox());
```